# How to paint bucket to image like paint bucket tool on photoshop

Tags: ios, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flood Fill Algorithm - Objective C Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121348/flood-fill-algorithm-objective-c-version)

I want to paint color to area in image (not all area, assume I want to paint color to circle in image) it seem the paint bucket tool on photoshop. How should I do?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 1):

Are you having trouble deducing the shape to fill, or the flood fill algorithm? I infer from your question that most of your trouble is with the algorithm.

Direct from wikipedia, here is the psuedo-algorithm for flood fill.

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 2. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 3. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 4. Return.
```

[<sup><sup><sup><sup>[Source]</sup></sup></sup></sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

[image]

Comment: I have  trouble deducing the shape to fil

Comment: I'm a beginner for iOS Developer TT

Comment: Have you managed to draw a shape ok? Consider modifying the algorithm slightly so that instead of taking a target color, it takes an edge color and returns when it reaches a pixel of that edge color.